# Reactive Extensions: Allowing only a single subscriber for each type

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is there a way to ensure that there can be at most one subscriber registered per type for a generic type? An example would explain it better:

```
public interface Message
{

}

public class Command : Message
{

}

public class Event : Message
{

}

public class Bus
{
    private readonly IObservable<Message> _stream;
    private readonly Subject<Message> _subject;

    public Bus()
    {
        _subject = new Subject<Message>();
        _stream = _subject.AsObservable();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe<T>(IObserver<T> observer) where T:Command
    {
        return _stream.OfType<T>().Subscribe(observer);
    }

    public void Execute<T>(T command) where T:Command
    {
        _subject.OnNext(command);
    }
}
```

I'd like to ensure that more than one observer cannot subscribe to the same type of Command. Is there something in Rx that allows that, or am I limited to:
a) Keep a lookup of types myself or
b) Not deal with it during registration, and use an interim subscriber to detect multiple registrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that Rx provides any built in mechanisms for this.  Given your example code, I'd just make a `Dictionary<Type, IObserver<T>>` and use it within your `Subscribe` method to enforce your constraint.

Comment: That's kind of the conclusion I'm coming to as well. Thanks.